# Last Row and Offset Combination

Tags: vba, excel

I cant find out what is problem with this code. when I run it I got compile error for LRow. I would be grateful if you help. Thanks in advance.

```
Dim NameTxb As String
Dim DateTxb As Date
Dim WYSTxb As Date
Dim WYETxb As Date
Dim DivCmb As String
Dim PosCmb As String
Dim VacCmb As Integer
Dim Add1Cmb As Integer
Dim Add2Cmb As Integer
Dim MDB As Worksheet:                   Set MDB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MainDataBase")
Dim LRow As Long:                       LRow = MDB.Cells(MDB.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With Worksheets("MainDataBase").LRow
        LRow.Offset(1, 0).Value = AddWorker.NameTxb.Value
        LRow.Offset(0, 1).Value = AddWorker.DivCmb.Value
        LRow.Offset(0, 2).Value = AddWorker.PosCmb.Value
        LRow.Offset(0, 3).Value = AddWorker.DateTxb.Value
        LRow.Offset(0, 4).Value = AddWorker.WYSTxb.Value
        LRow.Offset(0, 5).Value = AddWorker.WYETxb.Value
        LRow.Offset(0, 6).Value = AddWorker.VacCmb.Value
        LRow.Offset(0, 7).Value = AddWorker.Add1Cmb.Value
        LRow.Offset(0, 7).Value = AddWorker.Add2Cmb.Value
```

End With
End sub

Comment: Lrow will just be a number, not the row.  SO you need to say `Worksheets("MainDataBase").row(lrow)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With MDB
    .Range("A" & LRow).Offset(1, 0).Value = 
    .Range("A" & LRow).Offset(0, 1).Value =
```

Answer (score 0):

Lrow will just be a number, not the row. SO you need to say `Worksheets("MainDataBase").row(lrow)`